# Toolbar jumping in place when view appears

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-toolbar

I have a view with a toolbar at the bottom that I am navigating to using a `NavigationLink`. But when the view appears, the toolbar is shown a little too low. After half a second or so it then suddenly jumps into place. It only happens the first time after the app is started. If I go back to the first view and start the navigation again it is shown in the correct place immediately.

Here are the files to reproduce it:

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                ToolbarView()
            } label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ToolbarView:

```
struct ToolbarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Text1")
                Text("Text2")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a SwiftUI bug?

Here are pictures before and after the jump. Check the trash at the bottom. If the toolbar has a color it is of course even more obvious.

[image: Before the jump]

[image: After the jump]

Comment: It is better to see once than to hear hundred... anyway you really don't need spacebar there (at least w/o container).

Comment: @Asperi I have added pictures. You are right I don't need the space. That was because I copied the sample project from a bigger app that I am working on

Comment: I've seen (a variant of) this issue as well. The jumpiness was quite obvious in my case when toggling a `Toggle` in the child view: The toggle and its label text would jump up. If the bottom toolbar in the parent view was removed, the jump didn't occur in the child view. Additional note: The issue seems to occur only with the bottom toolbar placement, and none of the other placements I've tried.

Comment: I know that that this is a little hacky, but if you embed your `ScrollView` into a `NavigationView`, the weird animation stops

Answer (score 2):

1. You will get the worst effect on iOS 16 with your code which is **not showing the toolbar at all!** So first, add specify the style of the navigation using the following modifier on the `navigationView`:

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

2. If both the first and second view does not have the same containers, you will see unexpected movements, so you can add an empty toolbar for holding the place to the `navigationLink`:

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) { Spacer() }
```

---

The completed code would be:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                ToolbarView()
            } label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) { Spacer() }  // <- prevents main page jumpings
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack) // <- prevents detail page jumping
    }
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Demo]
<sub>Don't worry about the RTL layout</sub>